# MySQL query joining rows in same table

Tags: mysql

I store sensor data in a MySQL table. The table has the fields id, timestamp, mac, temp and humidity.

Id is an unique autoincrement index, timestamp the time when the data was entered, Mac the Mac address of the sensor.

So for each sensor at each timestamp an entry is created. If all sensors are working the timestamp will be equal, but it can be that some sensors are not reachable.

I know want to query the temperatures of all sensors at all timestamps. For 3 sensors I came up with the following:

```
SELECT a.timestamp, a.temp, b.temp, c.temp from `data` as a 
inner join data as b on a.timestamp = b.timestamp
inner join data as c on a.timestamp = c.timestamp 
where a.mac = 'xx:xz:xz:34:03:F0' and 
b.mac = 'xz:xx:xx:34:C6:99' and 
c.mac='xx:xx:xx:32:27:36' order by a.timestamp
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO `data` (`id`, `mac`, `timestamp`, `temp`, `humidity`, `battery`) VALUES
(132, '58:2D:34:32:27:36', '2020-02-01 19:30:11', '23.2', '53.5', '0.0'),
(133, '58:2D:34:34:C6:99', '2020-02-01 19:30:11', '23.1', '51.4', '0.0'),
(134, '58:2D:34:34:03:F0', '2020-02-01 19:30:11', '24.1', '50.0', '0.0'),
(138, '58:2D:34:32:27:36', '2020-02-01 19:40:08', '23.2', '54.3', '0.0'),
(139, '58:2D:34:34:C6:99', '2020-02-01 19:40:08', '23.2', '51.6', '0.0'),
(140, '58:2D:34:34:03:F0', '2020-02-01 19:40:08', '24.1', '50.1', '0.0'),
(141, '58:2D:34:32:27:36', '2020-02-01 19:50:08', '23.3', '54.6', '0.0'),
(142, '58:2D:34:34:C6:99', '2020-02-01 19:50:08', '23.2', '51.4', '0.0'),
(143, '58:2D:34:34:03:F0', '2020-02-01 19:50:08', '24.0', '50.3', '0.0');
```

Example output:

```
Timestamp.         , Mac1, Mac2, Mac3
2020-02-01 19:30:08, 24.0, 23.2, 23.0
2020-02-01 19:40:08, 24.0, 23.1, 23.0
2020-02-01 19:50:12, 24.1, 23.1, 23.0
```

But I think there should/could be a more efficient way?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and sample output?

Comment: It doesn't look like you posted a working query (typo in the second row). Perhaps you could provide some expected output to help clarify what you are looking for. My hunch is what you really want to do is GROUP BY timestamp and use GROUP_CONCAT to get the various sensor temps for that particular timestamp. In that scenario your WHERE clause would change to be `where mac in ('mac1', 'mac2', ...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach would be to group by timestamp and use GROUP_CONCAT to get the sensor data for that timestamp.

```
SELECT 
timestamp, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(mac, ':', temp)) as temps
from data  
where mac in ('xx:xz:xz:34:03:F0', 'xz:xx:xx:34:C6:99', 'xx:xx:xx:32:27:36')
group by timestamp
order by timestamp
```

You'll also want an index on timestamp (even if you stick with your original approach). More info on the options for GROUP_CONCAT [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: I see you've provided an example. GROUP_CONCAT will give you the result all in one column rather than broken into separate columns per mac (though you can format it in a readable way within that column). If you definitely need that other format then it's possible your first approach is the only way to do it, but that gets messy if your list of macs grows.

Comment: I see. Just tried your suggestion and it returns indeed a single column but also a single row only... O.k. got it: group by instead of order by. Thanks that works!

Comment: Whoops, the single row was because I forgot to add the group by statement...answer edited. Sorry about that. Glad it helped.